# Why I'm getting IOException when making NFC tag read only

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I'm doing my `NFC` writing in the `AsyncTasks` `doInBackground()`. When I write NdefRecord it works well but when I'm trying to make tag read only I'm getting `IOException`. Here is the code where exception occurs:

```
  if (readOnly && !ndef.canMakeReadOnly()) {
        throw new NdefCantMakeReadOnlyException(R.string.cant_make_read_only);
    } else if (readOnly) {
        ndef.makeReadOnly(); //IOException
    }
```

This makeReadOnly works with Mifare Ultralight (MF0ICU1) tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsing through the Android 4.4.2 source (I did not check with older versions) reveals that you will always get an `IOException` if `makeReadOnly()` fails for whatever reason. So you found a bug in Android or at least a mismatch with the API documentation.

The cause is that `android.nfc.tech.Ndef` (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r1/core/java/android/nfc/tech/Ndef.java), starting on line 383) expects the NFC service to return `ErrorCodes.SUCCESS` for successful locking, `ErrorCodes.ERROR_INVALID_PARAM` for failed locking and `ErrorCodes.ERROR_IO` on any IO related error. However, the NFC service returns ErrorCodes.SUCCESS if locking succeeds (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-4.4.2_r1/src/com/android/nfc/NfcService.java), line 1438) and ErrorCodes.ERROR_IO if locking fails for any reason (see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Nfc/+/android-4.4.2_r1/src/com/android/nfc/NfcService.java), line 1440). `ErrorCodes.ERROR_INVALID_PARAM` seems not to be returned at all, thus the `makeReadOnly()` method should typically never return `false`.