# Android makeReadOnly() throws IOException

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

For an Android-App I want to write a message on a NDEF-Tag and make sure that the message cannot be altered afterwards. The obvious solution is the method makeReadOnly(), but it always throws a java.io.IOException without a message (null).
I have already tried the following:

- Check if the tag is writable
- Wrote a message on the tag
- Check with canMakeReadOnly() if it is in theory possible to make the tag read-only
- Use makeReadOnly in another Thread then the main-thread
- Sealed a tag with the app Tag-Writer, to make sure that the tags I use can be sealed at all
- Found out that IOException is the default-exception for this method, so maybe the error has nothing to do with I/O ([Why I'm getting IOException when making NFC tag read only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529387/why-im-getting-ioexception-when-making-nfc-tag-read-only)) but the answer there only explains that the exception doesn't need to be an IOException, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Here comes the concerning code:

```
                try {
                ndefTag.connect();

                if(ndefTag.canMakeReadOnly()) {
                    Log.d("Schuetzen", "makeReadOnly is possible");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("Schuetzen", "makeReadOnly is not possible");
                }

                if(ndefTag.isWritable())
                {
                    Log.d("Schuetzen", "Tag isWritable");
                }

                ndefTag.makeReadOnly();
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("myThread", e.toString());
            }

            finally {
                // Close connection:
                try {
                    ndefTag.close();
                    Log.d("myThread", "Tag closed");
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Logcat looks like this:

```
06-10 09:51:04.851  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter D/Schuetzen﹕ makeReadOnly is possible
06-10 09:51:04.851  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter D/Schuetzen﹕ Tag isWritable
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ java.io.IOException
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.nfc.tech.Ndef.makeReadOnly(Ndef.java:394)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter.myThread.doInBackground(myThread.java:34)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
06-10 09:51:04.898  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter D/myThread﹕ java.io.IOException
06-10 09:51:04.914  32274-14000/net.bits_bremen.bruenjes.gleisteinwriter D/myThread﹕ Tag closed
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I'm getting IOException when making NFC tag read only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21529387/why-im-getting-ioexception-when-making-nfc-tag-read-only)